# Hide result on table if previous record is same

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I have question like how to hide result if the previous record on loop like

```
$s="SELECT * from tabel";
$qs=mysqli_query($conn, $s);
echo "<table>";
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {
$tgl=date("d.m.y",strtotime($rs['tgl']));
$kode=$rs['kode'];
$desc=$rs['desc'];
echo "<tr><td>$tgl</td><td>$kode</td><td>$desc</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Example the date on previous record is the same date on next record, if value print on table sheet it looks double, the records only print if change or different. The date is same on next record (do not print) when the date is change then print. Also code only print if the code is change or different with previous record

This picture and code may illustrate what my points on it question
Thanks

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9pD8.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziGYz.jpg)

Result:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>DATE</td>
<td>KODE</td>
<td>DESC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2019-11-20</td>
<td>ISO123</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>DEF00</td>
<td>Column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2019-11-21</td>
<td>CCV09</td>
<td>Change</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>TRI124</td>
<td>Hide</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Duplicate</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your PHP Code which is creating this table.

Comment: Create variables to keep track of the previous columns' content and show it if it's different

Comment: @benipr Check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: yes i have add php code @ascsoftw

Comment: @ThumChoonTat would you like to give me examplle how the code identify previous loop like $num=0; $num++

Comment: @benipr Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$prev_tg1 = $prev_kode = '';  //Create Placeholders.

while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qs)) {
    $tgl = date("d.m.y",strtotime($rs['tgl']));
    $kode = $rs['kode'];
    $desc = $rs['desc'];

    if( $prev_tg1 == $tg1 ) {  //Check same as previous
        $tg1 = '';              //set it to empty if same
    } else {
        $prev_tg1 = $tg1;      //Update the Placeholder
    }

    if( $prev_kode  == $kode ) {
        $kode = '';
    } else {
        $prev_kode  = $kode;
    }   
    echo "<tr><td>$tgl</td><td>$kode</td><td>$desc</td></tr>";
}
```